# Get all words from text file (Java)

Tags: java, file, loops, java.util.scanner, cpu-word

I am trying to display all words in a file that can be found horizontally and vertically and I am trying print the location of the first character of each word (row and column).

I got it to display every word horizontally but not vertically.

This is the code I used so far

```
public class WordFinder {
    public static final String WORD_FILE = "words.txt";
    public static void find(){
        try {
            File file = new File(WORD_FILE);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNext() == true) {
                String s = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```

It should search the file horizontally and vertically to find words. Once it finds a word it should display the location of the first letter of the word (E.G. `grammar: row 8, position 1`) At the moment it just prints all horizontal words.

Comment: Enter the lines of `words.txt` in a `char[][]` then implement a function that searches a word in the `char[][]`. You might use `String.toCharArray()`.

Comment: Is every line same lengt?

Comment: All lines are different lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to count the line number and position of the words while iterating. Therefore you should use `scanner.hasNextLine()` and `scanner.nextLine()`. After that you can split the line:

```
int lineNumber = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    int positionNumber = 0;
    for (String word : line.split("\\s")) {
        if (!word.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(word + ": line " + (lineNumber + 1) + ", position " + (positionNumber + 1));
        positionNumber += word.length() + 1;
    }
    lineNumber++;
}
```

This splits the line on all whitespaces (`\\s`) and handle double whitespaces (empty words) with `if (!word.isEmpty())`.